# urlparse fails with simple url

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlparse

this simple code makes `urlparse` get crazy and it does not get the hostname properly but sets it up to `None`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
parsed = urlparse("google.com/foo?bar=8")
print(parsed.hostname)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-2.1:

> Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters. The lower case
> letters "a"--"z", digits, and the characters plus ("+"), period ("."),
> and hyphen ("-") are allowed. For resiliency, programs interpreting
> URLs should treat upper case letters as equivalent to lower case in
> scheme names (e.g., allow "HTTP" as well as "http").

Using advice given in previous answers, I wrote this helper function which can be used in place of `urllib.parse.urlparse()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import urllib.parse

def urlparse(address):
    if not re.search(r'^[A-Za-z0-9+.\-]+://', address):
        address = 'tcp://{0}'.format(address)
    return urllib.parse.urlparse(address)

url = urlparse('localhost:1234')
print(url.hostname, url.port)
```

A previous version of this function called `urllib.parse.urlparse(address)`, and then prepended the "tcp" scheme if one wasn't found; but this interprets the username as the scheme if you pass it something like "user:pass@localhost:1234".

Answer (score 3):

`google.com/foo?bar=8` is a relative URL aka a "path" with a "query". Perhaps you see `google.com` as a hostname, but it doesn't have to be (and how would python know?)

URLs consist of protocol or scheme ('https:', 'ftp:', etc.), host ('//example.com'), path, query, fragment.

So urlparse is making it's best guess, returning None for protocol and host.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some further context to Muadh's answer. Look at the output from these two variations using urlparse:

```
>>> parsed = urlparse("google.com/foo?bar=8")
>>> parsed
ParseResult(scheme='', 
            netloc='', 
            path='google.com/foo', 
            params='', 
            query='bar=8', 
            fragment='')
```

And with the full path specified

```
>>> parsed = urlparse("http://google.com/foo?bar=8")
>>> parsed
ParseResult(scheme='http', 
            netloc='google.com', 
            path='/foo', 
            params='', 
            query='bar=8', 
            fragment='')
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work properly you have to include the protocol identifier (http://). This is what worked for me:

```
parsed = urlparse("https://www.google.com/foo?bar=8")
print(parsed.hostname)
```

The output from here was: www.google.com (which seems expected). More can be read about how to use urlparse [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html).

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Yes, I know that works but what if I have a list that does not specify the schema? Actually it's not that weird that they don't

Comment: Your link to `urlparse` references python2. `urlparse` is imported differently in python3

Comment: In this case I would check and see if it has a protocol identifier, and if not add it to the string before parsing.

Comment: @ScottMcC Ah thanks for catching that, I fixed the link.